# IsolatedStorage in MvvmCross

Tags: mvvmcross

I am creating an Android App using MvvmCross.

Before calling some service,I want my MvxActivity should first check app's isolated 
storage  whether that data is present in its isolatedStorage, if it is then it should 
populate its UI controls(eg. ListView,Spinner etc.)by fetching data from
isojatedstorage otherwise call service and then populate them using data received from  service.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use File plugin for MvvmCross

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#file

Comment: Is this an IsolatedStorage? It doesn.t include methods for creating files.It just includes operation such as read,write and other?I am new to this.Please elaborate clearly...

Comment: Yes, it's stores the files in the application folder which is similar to IsolatedStorage (although there is no concept of IsolatedStorage on Android).

Comment: But how to create a new file ?

Comment: Just write into a file, if it doesn't exist it will be created. You can see the source code of this plugin on Github.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use that plugin for Android (i didnt dig to deep inside), but for Windows  Phone i had used [this solution](https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/jet-image-loader) for downloading/storing images and here is my own [lib for storing any text data in the isostorage](https://isostoragemanager.codeplex.com/) (serialization/deserailzation is included).

Answer (score 0):

I use PCLStorage, it's cross platform. Just search for it on NuGet.